# reading llvm bitcode in python

Tags: python, llvm

Is there a way to parse llvm bitcode from python? I found [this](http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html) but I'm not sure if it supports reading from an object file. I tried calling `from_path` in [the ObjectFileRef class](http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/binding/object-file.html) but it just segfaults.

Comment: http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/binding/modules.html#llvmlite.binding.parse_assembly

Comment: Depends on what you want it parsed 'in to"? `llvm-dis` disassembles to llvm IR for example.